# Why I can't perform this simple JavaScript function using the onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, xhtml, dom-events

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

Into a JSP page I have the following "link":

```
<tr onmouseout="Javascript: this.style.background='#FFFFFF'; 
                            this.style.color='#003399';" 
                            onmouseover="Javascript: this.style.background='#003399'; 
                            this.style.color='#FFFFFF'; this.style.cursor='hand';" 
                            onclick="changeLocationTo('edi.do?serv=4.U');">

    <td style="border-top: 0px;">
        Tabella Anagrafica
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, when the user click on the **tr** element it is performed the `changeLocationTo()` JavaScript function passing to it the String `'edi.do?serv=4.U'`.

Into this page I have defined the **script** section:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/Script.js">
    function changeLocationTo(newLocation) {

        alert("INTO changeLocationTo, nweLocation: " + newLocation);
        loadingPopUp();

        // you may add an timeout here or to handle a popup action like closing it

        document.location.href = newLocation;
    }
</script>
```

My problem is that when I click on the previous **tr** link it don't perform the `changeLocationTo()` function and into the **FireBug** console is is shown this error message every time that I click on the **tr**:

> ReferenceError: changeLocationTo is not defined

Why? what could be the problem? How can I try to fix it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `script` element has a `src` attribute so the code inside it is ignored and the script from the URL is loaded instead.